# In spinning, twist accumulates in the thinnest parts of yarn. Why?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque

If you're spinning yarn from some kind of fibre, areas of the yarn that are slightly thicker (i.e. the fibres aren't drafted out/pulled apart and stretched out as much) don't twist much while the thinnest spots tend to develop the most twist. You can twist a thick part of yarn excessively, but once the twist has a chance to travel up the yarn, it distributes itself according to the diameter of the yarn.

What causes this physical phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

The yarn can be modeled, very roughly, as a torsion spring. The torque $\tau$ required for a particular angular deflection ("twist") $\theta$ is given by:

$$\tau = \kappa\theta$$

The constant $\kappa$ is called the *torsion constant*. For an object with a uniform circular cross section, $\kappa$ is related to three quantities: the length $L$ of the yarn, the shear modulus $G$ of the yarn, and a geometry factor $J$:

$$\kappa = \frac{GJ}{L}$$

The important part of this for our purposes is the geometry factor $J$ (the rest doesn't depend on the thickness of the yarn). For an object with circular cross section of radius $r$:

$$J=\frac{\pi r^4}{2}$$

So it's clear that for the thinner sections of the yarn, the geometry factor $J$ is much smaller, which means that the torsion constant $\kappa$ is much lower, which means that they're far easier to twist than thicker sections of the yarn. Therefore, twist tends to accumulate in the thinner parts.